# Element is not moving with the data received by jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

I want to change the position of icon1 and icon2 with the data received from ajax.

"result" is div element. It works fine by showing the message received from ajax but I wonder why "icon1" and "icon2" is not moving. Message does received and "result" element does changing every 0.5sec and shows me the result. Weird?!

I tried following code on chrome but it doesn't work. What should I do on my code. I haven't tried it on other browser, if the browser beside chrome works, please let me know. Thank you.

```
setInterval(function(){

    // post data
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8080",
        data: {id:mId,color:mColor,x:mX,y:mY}
    }).done(function(msg){

        // result is div element
        result.text(JSON.stringify(msg) );          


    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        result.text( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });

    var jObj = jQuery.parseJSON( result.text() );               

    // icon1 and icon2 is div element
    icon1.css({
        position:"absolute",top:(jObj[0].y),left:(jObj[0].x)
    }); 
    icon2.css({                         
        position:"absolute",top:(jObj[1].y),left:(jObj[1].x)
    });

}, 500);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ajax is asynchronus!!! you should always write your codes inside the success function of ajax to make sure the ajax has returned the required value..try this

```
setInterval(function(){

// post data
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080",
    data: {id:mId,color:mColor,x:mX,y:mY}
}).done(function(msg){

    // result is div element
    result.text(JSON.stringify(msg) );          
     var jObj = jQuery.parseJSON( result.text() );               

    // icon1 and icon2 is div element
    icon1.css({
       position:"absolute",top:(jObj[0].y),left:(jObj[0].x)
    }); 
    icon2.css({                         
        position:"absolute",top:(jObj[1].y),left:(jObj[1].x)
    });

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    result.text( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});

}, 500);
```

OR making it a bit cleaner...(and edited after the answer)

```
setInterval(function(){

// post data
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080",
    data: {id:mId,color:mColor,x:mX,y:mY}
}).done(function(msg){

    // result is div element
    result.text(JSON.stringify(msg) );          

    changeCss();

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    result.text( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    changeCss();
});

}, 500);

function changeCss(){
     var jObj = jQuery.parseJSON( result.text() );
     icon1.css({
       position:"absolute",top:(jObj[0].y+"px"),left:(jObj[0].x+"px")
    }); 
    icon2.css({                         
        position:"absolute",top:(jObj[1].y+"px"),left:(jObj[1].x+"px")
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @bipen for your solution. I have tried you code out but it still don't works.

After I used your code and do some edit and it works. Maybe the solution is quite noobs, but it works nicely after I added "px" on the behind of the jObj.

```
function changeCss(){
     var jObj = jQuery.parseJSON( result.text() );
     icon1.css({
       position:"absolute",top:(jObj[0].y+"px"),left:(jObj[0].x+"px")
    }); 
    icon2.css({                         
        position:"absolute",top:(jObj[1].y+"px"),left:(jObj[1].x+"px")
    });
}
```

Anyway, +1 as it does solved 50% of my problems.

Comment: oops !!!! ya i was just copy pasting your answer and was concentrating on what the actual problem was..there should be `px` anyways glad you found it yourself.. :)..happy coding